# iCloud sharing among other users

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, icloud

From what i know, iCloud is like a personal storage and you uses your own Apple ID for it.
What i want to ask is that, is it possible for users to store for example an image and be shared with other users?

Which means something like DropBox. You upload files into your DropBox account and there will be a url that allows other people to download the file.

Does iCloud has this kind of function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about facilities on Apple's iCloud service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably better answered on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

However, as of right now, the answer is no. iCloud isn't a multi-user file sharing service. The only way to share documents, photos, or other data is to email, tweet, or MMS a copy.

Comment: Yes ... unfortunately this is one part of iCloud that still makes other cloud storage services (like Dropbox) necessary for some apps. It is possible to share between users in the same family if you set up your devices properly, however. In my family, my iCloud account is the "main" account for all devices. My wife has her own iCloud account that is added as a secondary account on her devices, and it is used to sync the services that she doesn't want to share with me. We will be able to "iCloud" share document data between us, although this same procedure would not really work with others.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity ... they seem to be sharing iClouds ... how does this work or does apple support this now ?

http://www.busymac.com/busycal/userguide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can share calendar data through iCloud. Don't know about any other apps.

http://www.busymac.com/busycal/userguide/caldav-sharing.html