# iOS - Syncing some data, all data and with and without other users, advice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, synchronization

I'm looking into adding some syncing features to my app and I haven't decided what type of syncing to implement. I've done some basic reading into icloud and I already use dropbox to backup my apps database.

My options are full sync of my database, where I think iCloud would be best. However, if this needs to be shared without another user, I don't think iCloud allows this ?

Syncing an account (e.g. a savings account). I haven't read in-depth about the Dropbox sync api, so I'm not sure if it works like the dropbox backup. It seems like there's a central database, but I'm not user if there are user databases too.

I haven't decided how the sync would work, I know the dropbox api will allow syncing of files based on modification data, so I could just have a file full of sql transactions for each account.

Can anyone will in any of the blanks and give me some advice about their experiences ?

I'm currently not using core data, but sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in saying that [iCloud doesn't support syncing between multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762792/icloud-sharing-among-other-users).

It's hard to comment on good technology alternatives without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve. Can you elaborate please?

If you're synching between different users, Dropbox doesn't sound appropriate either.